# Testing the safeMint function

Tags: tokens, erc-721, testing

I am trying to successfully write a unit test for my safeMint function below.

Here is my current test:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const { accounts } = require("@openzeppelin/test-environment");
const ComNFT = artifacts.require("ComNFT");
const { expect } = require("chai");

// describe('ComNFT', () => {
// let accounts;
let comNFT;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  comNFT = await ComNFT.new({ from: accounts[0] });
  //comNFT = await ComNFT.at("");
  // console.log(comNFT.address);
});


  it('should fail when called by a non-owner account', async () => {
    try {
      await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[1], // The non-owner account
        to: comNFT.address, // The contract address
        data: comNFT.methods.safeMint(accounts[1], 'token URI').encodeABI() // The function call and arguments, encoded as ABI
      });
      assert.fail('Expected error not thrown');
    } catch (error) {
      assert(error.message.includes('onlyOwner'), 'Expected "onlyOwner" error message not found');
    }
  });

  it('should be able to mint a new token', async () => {
    await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
      from: accounts[0], // The owner account
      to: comNFT.address, // The contract address
      data: comNFT.methods.safeMint(accounts[1], 'token URI').encodeABI() // The function call and arguments, encoded as ABI
    });

    const tokenURI = await comNFT.tokenURI(1); // Assume the token ID is 1
    assert.equal(tokenURI, 'token URI');
  });
```

```
    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }
```

I am getting a failure message after i run npx truffle test "  1) "before each" hook for "should fail when called by a non-owner account"

0 passing (3s)
1 failing

1. "before each" hook for "should fail when called by a non-owner account":
   TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
   at Context. (test/ComNFT.js:11:12)"

Can someone suggest a way of me successfully writing a test that calls safeMint?

The other test  "itshould fail when called by a non-owner account" is also not running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reason of error `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` is:
`accounts` is declared as `const` at

> const { accounts } = require("@openzeppelin/test-environment");

But you assign it again at

> beforeEach(async () => {
> accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
> ...

About the unit test, consider using `beforeAll` to setup the contract if each test case is standalone and without dependency or collision. Otherwise, deploy a new contract for each test case.
This post might help: [How to make Truffle tests run separately without contaminating state](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61343/how-to-make-truffle-tests-run-separately-without-contaminating-state)

---**Edit 1**---
In your code there are 3 tests, they do not depend on each other, but they really should.
`pause` and `unpause`  should check current status, and `safeMint` should check `pause` status, maybe a `onlyUnpaused` modifier is needed. So, test cases will all depend on `paused` status, it's collision.

Summary: Each test case should have its own contract.

Pseudo code:

````
async function deployContract() {
  // ...
}
describe("SomeTest", function () {
  it("testA", async function () {
    const contract = await deployContract();//
    //test code below
    // ...
  });
  it("testB", async function () {
    const contract = await deployContract();//
    //test code below
    // ...
  });
});```
````

Comment: Thanks for your initial input. I responded with an answer if you could take a look?